# How to pass dropdown values into mongodb in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I'm new to react.
I create a form which consist with input fields, button and drop-down menu. It's is a functional component. I need to pass selected drop-down items' id to back-end through axios with other form value. Before create drop-down other values that get from input fields could add pass to backend. Is there any way to pass values to back-end with other form input values? Here is my code.

```
const [course, setCourse] = useState({
    name: "",
    code: "",
    passMark: "",
    lic: "",
    subjects: [],
    options: []
});

//const [subject, setSubject] = useState();

async function getSubjects(){
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/subject")
    const data = res.data
    const option = data.map((item)=>({
        "value" : item._id,
        "label" : item.name
    }))

    setCourse({options: option})
}

/*function handleSelect(event){
    setSubject(event.target.value)
}*/

function handleClick(){
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/course/add",course).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
}

return (
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                    <Form.Label>Subjects</Form.Label>
                    <Select options={course.options} name="subjects" isMulti  />
                </Form.Group>

                 
            </Form>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Selected values don't pass to back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the `value` and `onChange` prop to the Select as you are doing for the other Input's as well . Also you need to separate out the `options` from your course else while posting you will send that as well.

So create a new state for `subject options`

```
const [course, setCourse] = useState({
name: "",
code: "",
passMark: "",
lic: "",
subjects: [],
});

const [ options, setOptions ] = useState(null);

async function getSubjects(){
const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/subject")
const option = data.map((item)=>({
    "value" : item._id,
    "label" : item.name
}))
setOptions (options)
}
```

And add the `value` and `onChange` prop for your select

```
<Select
  options={options}
  name="subjects"
  isMulti
  value={course.subjects}
  onChange={(selectedValues) => {
    setCourse((preValue) => {
      return {
        ...preValue,
        subjects: selectedValues,
      };
    });
  }}
/>
```

To send only subject Id's

```
function handleClick() {
  const requestData = {
    ...course,
    subjects: course.subjects.map((subject) => subject._id),
  };
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3000/course/add", requestData)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: what function are we referring here ? . Add a console.log(course) inside your `handleClick` function to check the course object .

Comment: When I add these code, It shown nothing in that react page.

Comment: Update your question with your latest code .

Comment: This is working. Thank you so much...... You are amazing. But small problem. I want to pass only subject _id. In here it pass all subject array. How can I pass only _id?

Comment: updated my answer to send only subject ids to the post call .